# FFT Frequency Analysis on LABView

Tags: arduino, signal-processing, fft, labview, adc

I'm newbie to digital signal processing. I'm currently trying to create a frequency analysis graph for my sensor which using the ADC of my arduino. The signal produced was in a voltage signal amplitude overtime. I wonder which was the correct FFT method of doing this? I'm currently dealing with this configuration:

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information so that we can help you. What is going wrong? Judging by the diagram, it seems that you should be getting out the FFT results. The signal produced isn't the amplitude over time, it is the magntitude versus frequency for waveform graph 4, hence f0 (inital frequency) and df (frequency step). Each element in magnitude represents the magnitude of the f0+index*df frequency, which is, along with the phase array, what you are looking for, no?

Comment: But the waveform I get from graph 4 was always remaining at 0 frequency: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Qfl.png. I wan to create an adjustment for me to about to read the frequency component ranging from 100Hz to 1000Hz in FFT.

Comment: How many data points are you feeding into the FFT? You can only get out as many as you put in during each window. If your window size is one, the FFT will output the one point as the magnitude.

Comment: I will be having a sensor like accelerometer, signal input from from 3 different channel x,y,z. I would combine the signal from all 3 analogue input and get a finalized fft output. I'm running the ADC at 10bits which is 1024 samples overtime. Could u help me out with this configuration? If i wanna determine my frequency at 100Hz in frequency domain?

Comment: Sorry, all I know about is the computation side. What number are you passing into the window? I don't know what VI you're using to construct the waveform, but you're only passing one value to it. If the waveform you pass to the FFT has one point in it, again, you are only going to get one value out. (Additionally, this sort of troubleshooting is more appropriate at the [NI Forums](http://forums.ni.com/) or [LAVA](http://lavag.org/); they'll be able to help in more detail.)